# Exclamation mark removed as for variable assignment side effect

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to process property file and replace some of the properties.
While I managed to implement it with

```
@echo OFF

set "file=my.properties"

(for /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%file%" ^| find /V /N ""') do (
  echo.%%B
)) > output.txt
```

as a side effect all exclamation marks (!) were removed from result file. Is this a bug in windows batch or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have delayed expansion enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could solve the problem with the exclamation marks with a `setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion`.
Because with enabled delayed expansion, the expansion of `%%B` drops the exclamation marks.

But there are some more problems.

Using `echo.` is slow and fails with some content in your file like `\..\windows\system32\calc.exe`.

`delims=]` removes the line number from `FIND /N` but it will also remove all `]` at the beginning of lines.

A better technic is to toggle the delayed expansion mode.

```
@echo OFF

set "file=my.properties"

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
(for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" "%file%"') do (
  set "line=%%A"
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set "line=!line:*:=!"
  (echo(!line!)
  endlocal
)) > output.txt
```

Comment: it is 00:15 now and it finally works! thanks a lot!

Comment: Jeb, isn't delayed expansion disabled by default?

Comment: @Squashman Yes, normally it should, but what if not, or this batch is called by another one ...

Comment: the trick is that for one command you need it enabled and for other you need it disabled, and you should change this while iterating the loop

Comment: I also added additional endlocal at the end in my script as we are using recursive setlocal-endlocal

Comment: The setlocal/endlocal inside the loop isn't recusive. But the use of an endlocal after the loop could be useful, as in front of the loop is an additional `setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion`